# How to add firebase to a fragment in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-fragments

I am making an android ecommerce app and I downloaded an app template but in that template there is no firebase in the fragment and I want when the user clicks checkout button the products he selected should go to the firebase database but all videos I see they use activities .So please help me.
**CartFragment.java**

```
 package com.example.shoppingcart.views;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
    import androidx.navigation.NavController;
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.Toolbar;
    
    import com.example.shoppingcart.R;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.adapters.CartListAdapter;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.cartholder;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.databinding.FragmentCartBinding;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.dataholder;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.models.CartItem;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.productholder;
    import com.example.shoppingcart.viewmodels.ShopViewModel;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
    
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    public class CartFragment extends Fragment implements CartListAdapter.CartInterface {
    
        private static final String TAG = "CartFragment";
        private ImageView productImage;
        private TextView productname;
        private TextView productprice;
        private TextView productcategory;
        private Spinner productquantity;
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String randomUUID = uuid.toString().trim();
        ShopViewModel shopViewModel;
        FragmentCartBinding fragmentCartBinding;
        NavController navController;
        Button button;
    
        private void finishActivity() {
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    
        public CartFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            fragmentCartBinding = FragmentCartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
            return fragmentCartBinding.getRoot();
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            
    
            navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
    
            final CartListAdapter cartListAdapter = new CartListAdapter(this);
            fragmentCartBinding.cartRecyclerView.setAdapter(cartListAdapter);
            fragmentCartBinding.cartRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    
            shopViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShopViewModel.class);
            shopViewModel.getCart().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<CartItem>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
                    cartListAdapter.submitList(cartItems);
                    fragmentCartBinding.placeOrderButton.setEnabled(cartItems.size() > 0);
                }
            });
    
            shopViewModel.getTotalPrice().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Double>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Double aDouble) {
                    fragmentCartBinding.orderTotalTextView.setText("Total: PKR " + aDouble.toString());
    
    
                }
            });
    
            button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.placeOrderButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CartFragment.this.getActivity(), CheckoutActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finishActivity();
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public void deleteItem(CartItem cartItem) {
            shopViewModel.removeItemFromCart(cartItem);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void changeQuantity(CartItem cartItem, int quantity) {
            shopViewModel.changeQuantity(cartItem, quantity);
        }
    
    
    
        }
```

**fragment_cart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".views.CartFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cartRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/cart_row"
            tools:itemCount="2"
            />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Total: PKR 26"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Proceed To Checkout"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of firebase database you have to use because both of the methods are similar...
activity and fragment method is same not any kind of change to the method ...

i will show you firestore method because i don't know which one you have to use

in fragment first initilize

```
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
```

oncreateview initialize

```
firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

after you can perform all your crud operation and all thing but first two line is require

simple use bro...

Comment: Thanks if you send me a tutorial link i will be grateful

Comment: This is my demo work  - https://github.com/axarlotwala/CloudFirestoreDemo